# Distance along x-axis between Global Maximum of a Wave Pattern and next Consecutive Maximum/Minimum

Tags: matlab

[image: Image of Wave Pattern]

I have a set of wave patterns (one example wave pattern included with the highest peak visible somewhere around x = 420) with various alternating peaks and troughs and have been able to determine the global maximum of the wave pattern using `max`. I now need to determine the distance along the 'x'-axis from this global maximum to the next consecutive local minimum immediately afterward and the distance to the next consecutive local maximum.

I have used findpeaks to find positive and negative peaks using the code as follows:

```
 pospks = findpeaks(h_dat(end,xi(i):xf(i)));
 negpks = findpeaks(-((h_dat(end,xi(i):xf(i)))))
```

since the negative version should return the minima.  `h_dat(end,xi(i):xf(i))` is just the code which returns the wave pattern based on my data (corresponding to multiple wave patterns with different parameters at 'end times' when a stable state has been reached with a corresponding stable global maximum).

I have attempted to sort them using the sort function but I am not sure if that helps as it will put them in ascending/descending order and you can see from my image that the heights of the local maxima and minima tend to be arbitrary so sorting them in ascending/descending order would not guarantee finding the distance from the highest peak (call it `hmax`) to the next maximum or minimum.  My idea was to use a distance function to find the distance from `hmax` to the next closest member of `pospks` and then to the closest member of `negpks` in order to find both relevant distances but have researched into it and still not sure how to do this (apologies if all this is very simple as I am quite new to Matlab).

Comment: Please, include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. See [recomendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to sort your peaks and take the first/last one, but please take the comment of Alexander into account.

Comment: Basically I have a large number of wave patterns, I have now given an example of what I am trying to analyse if you click the link 'Image of Wave Pattern' in my original post.  You can see on this pattern that there is a highest peak to the wave and I simply need to know the distance from here to the next minimum immediately following it and then the distance to the next maximum.

Comment: I have used findpeaks to find positive and negative peaks using the code as follows: ie pospks = findpeaks(h_dat(end,xi(i):xf(i)));
        negpks = findpeaks(-((h_dat(end,xi(i):xf(i)))))      since the negative version should return the minima.  I have also attempted to sort them but I am not sure if that helps as it will put them in ascending/descending order.  I have then tried to find the distance from the maximum peak to the next maximum found using pospks=findpeaks(f) but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply search for the first minimum that is after your global maximum, or the end of the data set if the maximum is last.

```
%% create the data set
x = rand(150,1);
idx = 55:85;
xx = x(idx);
xx = xx*max(x(:))/max(xx(:))*1.2; %% create a peak that will be in the middle of the data
x(idx) = xx;
x = smooth(x);
x = smooth(x);

%% find the next minimum
[pospks,locks] = findpeaks(x); %find all the maximums
[~,locksN] = findpeaks(-x);    %find only the location of all the minimums
[~,maxIdx] = max(pospks);      %find the location of the (first)global maximum
maxIdx = locks(maxIdx);
minIdxs = locksN(locksN > maxIdx); %find the indexes of all the minimums that are after the global maximum
if (isempty(minIdxs))
    minIdx = length(x); % take the last element of the dataset
else
    minIdx = minIdxs(1); % take the first min after the global max
end
plot(1:length(x),x,'green');
hold on;
plot(maxIdx,x(maxIdx),'bo');
plot(minIdx,x(minIdx),'r*');
hold off;
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: @Hollis, I've added some more comments, if you have more questions, ask.

Comment: Many thanks, could you also tell me how I would modify the code to find the first maximum after the global maximum?

Comment: Also, not sure if I have already been clear on this but I require the numerical value for the distance along the 'x'-axis between the global maximum and consecutive maxima/minima rather than just finding the location of the next minimum.

Comment: `locksN(locksN > maxIdx)` gives you the members of the vector `locksN` that have a value greater than `maxIdx`, in this case since `locksN` are the locations of the mins it gives you the location of all the mins that are after `maxIdx` (which is the index/location of the global max). If you want to do the same for the maxs, you just switch the vector `locks(locks > maxIdx)`. You have the location of the global max, and the next min (or max), to get the distance along the x-axis between them, simply subtract them: `d = minIdx-maxIdx`, if you want the difference in value: `x(maxIdx)-x(minIdx)`.